NIntegrate doesn't calculate a triple integral
I have an integral of dubious origin, which I don't know how to calculate:
NIntegrate[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]] / Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1] 
           Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}, {z, 0, ∞}]

Can anyone get Mathematica to calculate this? Thanks!

The improper integral under consideration diverges. To prove it let us switch to the spherical coordinates.
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][
Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]
Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}, {z, 0,  Infinity}], 
{r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Cartesian" -> "Spherical"]


Inactive[Integrate][ 1/Sqrt[1 + r^2] r^2 Cos[r Cos[\[Theta]]] Cos[r Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]]] Cos[ r Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]]] Sin[Sqrt[1 + r^2]] Sin[\[Theta]], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}, {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]/2}]

If the triple integral exists, then all 6 iterated integrals exist and equal to it.
Now consider the integral over r
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + r^2] r^2 Cos[r Cos[\[Theta]]] Cos[ r Cos[\[Theta]] *
Sin[\[Theta]]] Cos[r Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]]] Sin[Sqrt[1 + r^2]]*
Sin[\[Theta]], {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Theta] >= 0 && \[Theta] >= 0]


Integrate::idiv: Integral of (r^2 Cos[r Cos[[Theta]]] Cos[r Cos[[Theta]] Sin[[Theta]]] Cos[r Sin[[Theta]] Sin[[Phi]]] Sin[Sqrt[1+r^2]] Sin[[Theta]])/Sqrt[1+r^2] does not converge on {0,[Infinity]}.

This implies the divergence of the iterated integrals starting from the integration over r and the divergence of the triple integral under consideration.

(at)user64494 The same holds for the case D=2. For D=1 the integral is convergent and equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$

I think we can approximate this  integral as a limit (Solution idea is similar to the one-dimensional Cauchy Principal Value implemented in NIntegrate) !
Change of variables x->ArcTanh[u],y->ArcTanh[v],z->ArcTanh[w] transforms integration range to unitcube 0<u,v,w<1. New integrand is singular at u==1,v==1,w==1, though we try principal value approach:
int[eps_] := 
 NIntegrate[ 
  Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1] (
    Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z])/((1 - u^2) (1 - v^2) (1 - w^2)) /. {x -> 
     ArcTanh[u], y -> ArcTanh[v], z -> ArcTanh[w]}, {u, 0, 1 - eps}, {v, 
   0, 1 - eps}, {w, 0, 1 - eps}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

Result for small eps
Map[{#, int[#]} &, 10^-Range[5, 10]] // N
(* {{0.00001, 1.05742*10^-9}, {1.*10^-6, 1.05742*10^-11}, 
{1.*10^-7,1.05742*10^-13}, {1.*10^-8, 1.05742*10^-15}, 
{1.*10^-9,1.05743*10^-17}, {1.*10^-10, 1.05743*10^-19}}*)

The value of the integral tends to zero!
Hope it helps!

Can you kindly give a reference to the definition of such a "principal value"? Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Wiki say nothing about it. I think this is your invention. Think of its scientific publication.

@user64494 Have a look at Mathematica documentation PrincipalValue or in more detail Wikipedia Cauchy principal value. Unfortunately first publication is 200years ago.

Sorry, the documentation says nothing about multi-dimensional improper integrals.

(+1) I do not even see a reason why we should call it a principal value. The integral converges so it has its normal value.

@azerbajdzan Thanks for your comment. I'll modify my "wording"

@azerbajdzan : Can you kindly ground yor claim " The integral converges so it has its normal value"? Deep regard, as usually.

@UlrichNeumann: It is not a good practice to edit  an answer , not indicating the changes.

@UlrichNeumann It does not matter that integrand is singular at u=1, v=1, w=1 as long as the integral converges. Similarly  Integrate[1/x^(1/2), {x, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> False]==2 has singular integrand at x=0 yet it converges and it has its normal value, no need to call it principal value.

@UlrichNeumann On the other hand the following integral has only principal value. Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> False] returns "does not converge" but
Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True] == 0evaluates to0`.

@azerbajdzan That is clear to me. In both cases (your two last comments) one can exclude the singularities in an eps  neighborhood and prove convergence as eps->0 .

You can use NIntegrate to attempt a direct evaluation of the integral:
  Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]] / Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1] Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z], 
  {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}, {z, 0, ∞},
  Method -> "GlobalAdaptive", 
  PrecisionGoal -> 6
]


Your code is incomplete! What is your Mathematica version? On v12.2 your code doesn't evaluate.

It's v12.1NIntegrate[  Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1] Cos[x] Cos[    y] Cos[z], {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}, {z, 0, 12}, AccuracyGoal -> 4,   PrecisionGoal -> 4]

@Chan: Unfortunately,  NIntegrate[  Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1]]/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1] Cos[x] Cos[    y] Cos[z], {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, {z, -12, 12},   AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4] results in

"NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option

MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.19031636583095946 and 0.0004482034755553345 for the integral and error estimates.  " . I don't know good numeric methods for multi-dimensional improper integrals.
